# How to use Assert Contains in Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

Im trying to do some assertion in groovy, and I've found that Java allows you to check if a string contains a certain value, see below:

```
String longText;
String uan; 



Assert.assertThat(longText, CoreMatchers.containsString(uan));
```

Using the following imports:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.containsString;
```

Hwoever, groovy doesn't seem to like it and is throwing out error `"Missing Property Exception, No such property: Asset for class`

Does anyone know how I can use assert to check if a string "Contains" a value in Groovy?

**EDIT:**

Full Code:

```
def uan = "123"

String fileName = "C:\\Users\\xxx\\Desktop\\checklogs.txt";
def logs = faker.ivacsLogExtract().getMessages(fileName,uan );

Assert.assertthat(logs, CoreMatchers.containsString(uan));
```

Comment: The error says "Asset", isn't it the case that it should have been "assert" and that's what it complains about?

Comment: If you are using the static assertThat import, you don't have to use `Assert.assertThat(...)` you can just type `assertThat(...);`

Comment: @Compass, hmm tried it, still gives the same error

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo, yeah sorry, I made a mistake in the op, i meant to say Asser

Comment: Can you post the full code you have written?

Comment: @Compass, Done, I've added the full code

Comment: You are calling assertthat instead of assertThat.  Was that on purpose?

Comment: @Cogman, ohh, i didnt realise, let me try that

Comment: @Cogman, this is what I'm running: Assert.assertThat(logHello, CoreMatchers.containsString(uan)); - still not working

Answer (score 2):

I got it working by doing this:

assert longText.contains(uan)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the original code imports static methods, but then tries to use them in a conventional way (e.g. `Assert.assertThat`). Instead, try this (e.g. `assertThat`. see comment in code):

**Edit:** removed `@Grab` as it is confusing

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.containsString;

String longText = "abcdefijk";
String uan = "def";

// use methods without context:
assertThat(longText, containsString(uan));
```

Comment: Hmm, I tried that, but I'm getting the following error: NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/ivy/core/settings/IvySettings

Comment: If you already have JUnit on the classpath, you don't need the `@Grab` statement. I wrote the example as a standalone Groovy script. I will make an edit.